BadRequest error when trying to execute ForEach Activity in Azure Data Factory
I created a pipeline that executes a ForEach activity in ADF.
When I attempt to run the pipeline, I get the error:
{
"code": "BadRequest",
"message": null,
"target": "pipeline//runid/c37bfe58-0491-4be7-a25d-87521d92237e",
"details": null,
"error": null
}

I think the issue is with the 'Items' in my ForEach activity

The executions in the ForEach activity contain a Switch, and two pipelines,

Any idea what could be causing this error?

First of all, the expression used in 'Items' property of Foreach activity which is @activity(switch1).output is incorrect since Switch activity is inside the Foreach , it won't be able to evaluate the expression provided in items beforehand.
items in Foreach expects an expression which would return an array of items , through each of the items , activities inside ForEach will loop through.
Example: Suppose you create a metadata table in SQL having cols as schemaname and tablename
schemaname    tablename
dbo           table1
test          table2

Now , you could use lookup activity to fetch the data from this table to loop through each of the rows using foreach activity
Lookup--> Foreach(containing switch)
Items in Foreach will have expression @activity(lookup1).output.value
as value property will hold the array having the json of each record.
Now switch activity will run for each of the rows of the table in each iteration of the loop.
Hope it helps

thanks for getting in touch. I will try that suggestion and get back to you.
